# get NE and SW corners of a set of markers on a google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, bounds

I want to get NE and SW corners of a set of markers on a google map.  Here I iterate over each marker. Does google or javascript provide a function that gets this with less iteration?

```
  function fnSetBounds(){         
    var lowLat = 90;
    var highLat = -90;
    var lowLng = 180;
    var highLng = -180;

    for (var i = 0; i < myMarkers.length; i++) {

        var myLat = myMarkers[i].position['k'];
        var myLng = myMarkers[i].position['B'];

        // catch low LAT                                
        if (lowLat  >  myLat){
            lowLat  =   myLat; 
        }               
        // catch high LAT
        if (highLat <  myLat) {
            highLat =  myLat; 
        }

        // catch low LNG
        if (lowLng  >  myLng){
            lowLng  =   myLng; 
        }               
        // catch high lng               
        if (highLng <  myLng) {             
            highLng =  myLng; 
        }
    }                   
    var southWestCorner = new google.maps.LatLng(highLat, lowLng);
    var northEastCorner = new google.maps.LatLng(lowLat, highLng);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();            

    bounds.extend(southWestCorner);         
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    bounds.extend(northEastCorner);         
    map.fitBounds(bounds);            
  }
```

Comment: 1. do not use internal properties of the Google Maps Javascript API objects (position['k'],position['B']), they can and do change with releases of the API.  2. There is a google.maps.LatLngBounds.extend function that adds a single google.maps.LatLng to a bounds.

Comment: hey. I stumbled on your site a few days ago. Absolute inspiration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way, add all the positions to an empty bounds:

```
function fnSetBounds(){         
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < myMarkers.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(myMarkers[i].getPosition());
  }                   
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

Comment: A1. thats what I was looking for.  Didn't understand how to use it before.